# how to get focus-follows-mouse over buffers in emacs?

Tags: emacs, focus, window, dot-emacs

Suppose I have a source file open and I launch a shell. I can hit C-x o to switch between the two buffers. But how can I get it so that when I move the mouse the buffer under the mouse gets focus, just like the "focus follows mouse" option common in window managers?

Comment: You can also use shift+arrows to jump between buffers, which is easier to type than C-x o

Comment: Hm, over here when I do that it starts selecting a region.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Set:

```
(setq mouse-autoselect-window t)
```

Answer (score 3):

Answering the shift+arrow comment, do in your .emacs:

```
(windmove-default-keybindings)
```